# express js app connected with mongo db showing error after deploying on vercel

Tags: express, deployment, vercel

My ExpressJS app connected with MongoDB, showing an error after deploying on Vercel. Its running well on the local host, but when I deploy it using Vercel, it shows this error that "serverless function crashed." I am attaching the github repository link: [repo](https://github.com/himanshukandari14/campus.git) I want it to run after deploying. Please solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change replace this line in your code `vercel.json`:

`"use": "@now/node"`

With :

`"use": "@vercel/node"`

Remember, Vercel might have some limitations or differences compared to running your app locally. Review the Vercel documentation, their deployment guides, and error logs for more specific guidance on deploying Node.js applications with MongoDB to their platform. If you encounter specific errors or issues, feel free to share the relevant code snippets or error messages, and I can assist you further.